# Insert Excel formula via Powershell not working

Tags: excel, powershell, insert, formula

I would like to insert this formula with PowerShell into Excel:

```
=(IF(C2="Off";0;B2 * 0,075+D2 * 0,038)+E2 * 0,002) * 24 * 30,5
```

i tried it with backtick (`) but it does not work.

After I run the powershell script, the cell in which I am inserting the formula is blank.

Here is the full code:

```powershell
$Currency = '=(D2*"0,109")'

$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.visible = $True
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$b.worksheets.add()

$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$c.Cells.Item(1,2) = 'CPU'
$c.Cells.Item(1,3) = 'Power'
$c.Cells.Item(1,4) = 'RAM'
$c.Cells.Item(1,5) = 'Disk'
$c.Cells.Item(1,6) = 'Cost'
$c.Cells.Item(1,7) = 'Currency'

$d = $c.UsedRange
$d.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
$d.Font.ColorIndex = 1
$d.Font.Bold = $True

$c.Cells.Item(2,2) = '2'
$c.Cells.Item(2,3) = 'On'
$c.Cells.Item(2,4) = '8'
$c.Cells.Item(2,5) = '100'
$c.Cells.Item(2,6).Formula = "=(IF(C2=`"Off`";0;B2*`"0,075`"+D2*`"0,038`")+E2*`"0,002`")*24*`"30,5`""
$c.Cells.Item(2,7) = $Currency

$d.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$intRow = 2
```

Error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At C:\Users\admineb\Desktop\PSskript\Costs.ps1:38 char:1
+ $c.Cells.Item(2,6).Formula = "=(IF(C2=`"Off`";0;B2*`"0,075`"+D2*`"0,0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: You may try to wrap the formula string in single quotes ... like this: `$c.Cells.Item(2, 5).Formula = '=(IF(C2="Off";0;B2*"0,075"+D2*"0,038")+E2*"0,002")*24*"30,5"'`

Comment: Untested, but you may need to use `FormulaLocal` instead of `Formula`.

Comment: You might be in a region that uses commas for decimals (instead of points) but why are you wrapping numbers in double quotes? Your original Excel formula does not do so. Why not: `'=(IF(C2="Off";0;B2 * 0,075+D2 * 0,038)+E2 * 0,002) * 24 * 30,5'`?

Answer (score 0):

#PowerShell - Excel.Application uses FormulaLocal to assign an expression to Cell.Item(2,5).FormulaLocal :

```
$a=New-Object -comObject Excel.Application;
$a.visible = $True;
$a.workbooks.add();
$a.worksheets.add();
$a.worksheets.Item(1);
$a.Cells.Item(1,1);
$a.Cells.Item(1,2);

$a.Cells.Item(2,5).FormulaLocal = "=A1+B1";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working properly now.
Thank you for the very quick answer :-)

```
$c.Cells.Item(2,6).FormulaLocal = '=(IF(C2="Off";0;B2*"0,075"+D2*"0,038")+E2*"0,002")*24*"30,5"'
```

Is there an easy way to drag the fill handle with the formula above automatically down, with PowerShell?

I need to do this with over 1000 of excel row´s

Can the number "2" in "C2", "B2", "D2" and "E2" be exchanged with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, his is working now. :-)

Is there an easy way to drag the fill handle with the formula above automatically down, with PowerShell?

I need to do this with over 1000 of excel row´s

Can the number "2" in "C2", "B2", "D2" and "E2" be exchanged with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

it is working now.

(B2*"0,075"+D2*"0,038")+E2*"0,002")*24*"30,5"' doing this Math Formula directly in PS instead of Excel Formula.

Thanks for your support!